How to use tf.data.interleave() with tf.py_function
I am trying to build TF data pipeline with tf.data API. I have ~100k of npz files to load and each npz has key of ["input"] and ["output"]. Some preprocessing is needed before loading into the model with model.fit method.
Current implementation uses
def preprocess_fn(file_path):
  npz = np.load(file_path)
  input = npz["input"]
  input = do_preprocess(input)
  output = npz["output"]
  return input, output, file_path

dataloader = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("./train/*.npz")
dataloader = dataloader.map(
        lambda x: tf.py_function(preprocess_fn, [x], 
        [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.string]),
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
dataloader = dataloader.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

But since we have ~100k datasets and 4 A100 GPUs, dataloader became a bottleneck for training.
So I am trying to replace dataloader.map with dataloader.interleave, but it doesn't work as I thought.
I've tried multiple things to make it work, but none of it worked.

Replace map with interleave. This didn't work since interleave has to get dataloader, not Tensor as input.

dataloader = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("./train/*.npz")
dataloader = dataloader.interleave(
        lambda x: tf.py_function(preprocess_fn, [x], 
        [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.string]),
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)


Use tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(). This caused OoM of GPU.

dataloader = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("./train/*.npz")
dataloader = dataloader.interleave(
        lambda filepath: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        tf.py_function(preprocess_fn, [filepath],
        [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.string]),
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

Is there any way to use tf.data.interleave method with tf.py_function?

def py_function_wrapper(w):
    x,y,z = tf.py_function(your_func, [w], Tout=[tf.float32,tf.float32,tf.string])
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y,z))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.ones(100,))
dataset = dataset.interleave(py_function_wrapper, cycle_length=4, block_length=1, num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls)

